# EventHandler: Enable Button 2 when clicked on Button 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons in my HTML page, and I would like to incorporate a functionality that on clicking button "Show Fields", the Make Edits button should get enabled. Currently, the button Make Edits is diabled.
My HTML code is

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="showname" value="Show Fields" onclick ='editFunc()' style="margin-right: 5px;"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id = "makeEdits"  name="makeEdits" value="Make Edits" disabled ='disabled' style="margin-right: 5px;"/>
```

I have written Jquery for event handling :

```
function editFunc(){document.getElementById('makeEdits').disabled = false;}
```

The Make Edits button gets enabled for a second and then goes back to its normal state : i.e it becomes disabled.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery you don't need to use onClick, instead you give your button an id (in this case `showName`):

`<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="showname" value="Show Fields" id="showName" style="margin-right: 5px;"/>`

The you can do:

```
$("#showName").on('click', function(){
    $('#makeEdits').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/vhbq9pn1/1/)

Comment: I did the same, but the original problem is still existing.<script type="text/javascript">
$("#showName").on('click', function(){
    $('#makeEdits').prop('disabled', false);
});
<script>                                                           On clicking the button Show fields, Make Edit button gets enabled for a moment only. Can you let me know where I'm going wrong

Comment: I've updated my answer and JSFiddle based on the answer given by @steve padmore. You are using the `submit` type but you should be using `button` : `type="button"`.

Comment: But, I'm submitting a form with the Show Fields button, and that is fetching the rows from database. I tried using button, then the form is not getting posted to server. pls help.

Comment: OK, you will need to make some changes. Either you use an ajax request to update the page and then enable the button or, you will need to create some condition for when the button should be enabled i.e. when the form has been previously submitted. What you are doing is enabling the button then submitting the form, so it obviously won't remain enabled, as everything is reset. What language are you using for fetching the database records?

Comment: I'm using php for fetching the database records. I see your point that why the button is getting disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just a sample and simple code:

```
$("#activation_btn").on('click', function(){
    if($("#edit_btn").is(':disabled'))
        $("#edit_btn").prop('disabled', false); //$("#edit_btn").removeAttr('disabled');
    else
        $("#edit_btn").prop('disabled', true); //$("#edit_btn").addAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are clicking a Submit button. This will call the js code you have, and then immediately post back to the server and refresh the page. This is why the button is disabled again so quickly - the page is back to its original state...

Comment: any recommendation, how to overcome this ? I need the submit button as I'm sending a form with the help of that button

Comment: You are performing two separate functions here. 1st, submitting a form. This will lose anything you have changed on the page since it was originally loaded. 2nd, you want a button enabled *if you can make changes*. This means that this button should be enabled when the page is loaded/generated on the basis that there is data that can be edited. So, if loading with no data (a new record) - 'make edits' isn't applicable. If loading the page with a stored record, then 'make edits' is applicable. Otherwise the 'make edits' button should be the one that submits the form (to make an edit)...